# "Add to panel" doesn't work with indicator-applet-complete

Tags: gnome-panel

I've recently installed ubuntu 12.04 and I'm using gnome classique (gnome-panel.) Eveything is fine except that I have a problem when using 'add-to-panel' (super-key + alt + right-click): it works with anything but 'indicator-applet-complete', ie *nothing* is added to the panel.

I've tried to re-install packages and check configuration files but I couldn't fix this so far. So, has anybody experienced the same issue? Or did I miss something? Any hints are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, this is more likely a bug so I'd better file one.